# Avoid the use of escape characters in literal strings

Tags: objective-c, syntax, string-literals

Is there a way I can avoid escape sequences in literal strings in Objective-C?

For example, in C#, I can prefix the string with `@` and type the string normally, like: `@"C:\Users"`, without the use of the double backslash `"C:\\Users"`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Objective-C. A construction like `@"string"` generates an `NSString` object built from the plain `"string"`. And as far as I know, you cannot avoid escaping in the C language.

Comment: thats what i was afraid of :o